# EXISTS=`ssh xyz 'egrep "$username" /etc/passwd | cut -d':' -f1'` command is not working properly

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I am writing a script to add users on multiple linux servers. But first i want to check that mentioned username already exists on that particular server or not.

```
EXISTS=`ssh xyz 'egrep "$username" /etc/passwd | cut -d':' -f1'`
```

This is the command i am trying. But its not giving me the output that i want..rather its giving me the all username in passwd file.
The variable EXISTS should have the only that username or it should be empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On any modern Linux systems, you have `getent`. So instead of checking like this, check the return code (via `$?`) of:

```
getent passwd $username &>/dev/null
```

(exits with 0 if the user exists, 2 if it doesn't exist; other error codes described in the manpage)

(note: this is not really a Java question, is it?)

---

**EDIT** OK, full code...

```
ssh thehost getent passwd $username;
RC=$?;
# check for $RC here; if 0, the user exists; if not 0 it doesn't.
# Man getent for more details
```

Note that another solution would be to try and add the user directly; the command will fail if the user already exists, or some other reason; here again, man useradd, and check for possible return codes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but i believe it will only work if i enter getent passwd $uname... it will not work for getent /etc/passwd $uname.. so i have to do cd /etc then invoke this command..

Comment: No, not at all. Read the manpage for getent! `passwd` here is an OS database. More precisely, it reads configuration from `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.

Comment: so in this case , is this the right syntax ?? EXISTS=`ssh xyz 'getent passwd $username | cut -d':' -f1'`

Comment: no. see i dont want the error code, i want the username, so that i can compare it to find whether it is already present or not.

Comment: here is my code... 
 EXISTS=`ssh $i 'egrep "^$username" /etc/passwd | cut -d':' -f1'`
        if [ "$username" != "$EXISTS" ];then
               echo "Good to go"
                exit 1
        else
                echo "$username exists!"

        fi

Comment: Why do you want the username? This is ridiculous. Again: `getent passwd $username` will return 0 if `$username` is already present on the system, 2 if it isn't